# How to call MongoDB array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and I have this array saved on it.

The array looks something like this:

```
{
  playlistArray: [
    {
      title: 'Ocean Man Lyrics',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6E5m_XtCX3c',
      duration: '128',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6E5m_XtCX3c/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLCIpwHcxDNPrcMZYWiqCCK2h-Am8Q'
    },
    {
      title: 'Watermelon Man',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bjPlBC4h_8',
      duration: '392',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4bjPlBC4h_8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLCZGxFxw-tR8NGEtbwITKQqdh8u4w'
    },
    {
      title: 'Smash Mouth - All Star',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_jWHffIx5E',
      duration: '237',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L_jWHffIx5E/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLC2FgxHjd2CqZDtYIA9bv1FegnMYA'
    }
  ],
  username: "user name",
  playlistName: "playlist name"
}
```

However whenever I use mongoose to call the `playlistArray` array using

```
        let fetchList;
        fetchList = await playPlaylist.findOne({
            username: username,
            playlistName: playlistName
        });
        let newSongs = fetchList.playlistArray;
```

The `newSongs` would return :

```
[{"title":"Ocean Man Lyrics","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6E5m_XtCX3c","duration":"128","thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6E5m_XtCX3c/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLCIpwHcxDNPrcMZYWiqCCK2h-Am8Q"},{"title":"Watermelon Man","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bjPlBC4h_8","duration":"392","thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4bjPlBC4h_8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLCZGxFxw-tR8NGEtbwITKQqdh8u4w"},{"title":"Smash Mouth - All Star","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_jWHffIx5E","duration":"237","thumbnail":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L_jWHffIx5E/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLC2FgxHjd2CqZDtYIA9bv1FegnMYA"}]
```

Is there any way for it to return to something like this (remove quotes from the array object)?

```
[
    {
      title: 'Ocean Man Lyrics',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6E5m_XtCX3c',
      duration: '128',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6E5m_XtCX3c/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLCIpwHcxDNPrcMZYWiqCCK2h-Am8Q'
    },
    {
      title: 'Watermelon Man',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bjPlBC4h_8',
      duration: '392',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4bjPlBC4h_8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLCZGxFxw-tR8NGEtbwITKQqdh8u4w'
    },
    {
      title: 'Smash Mouth - All Star',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_jWHffIx5E',
      duration: '237',
      thumbnail: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L_jWHffIx5E/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLC2FgxHjd2CqZDtYIA9bv1FegnMYA'
    }
]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using `.map()`

```
let newSongs = fetchList.playlistArray.map((arr) => {
   // do something with arr
});
```